# Azure ApplicationGateWay requestRoutingRules are not being references when they are already defined

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I followed the application Gateway ARM template example and see no difference between the example and my script other than the waf inclusion. Found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/quick-create-template

My Application is saying the resource "requestRoutingRules" cannot find "httpListener", seems odd because I'm using the same variable to define it, unless is not being created. These are created inside APG so I cannot use dependsOn, I have no idea how to fix it now.

`2021-07-14T00:44:58.4999438Z ##[error]InvalidResourceReference: Resource...Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/mygateway/httpListeners/testHttpListener referenced by .....providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/mygateway/requestRoutingRules/testRoutingRule was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region. []`

Please take a look at "httpListener" and "requestingRoutingRules"

```
{
      "name": "[variables('applicationGatewayName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
      "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "zones": ["1"],
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIpAdressName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "app": "test"
      },
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "name": "WAF_v2",
          "tier": "WAF_v2"
        },
        "gatewayIPConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "appGatewayIpConfig",
            "properties": {
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "frontendIPConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "appGwPublicFrontendIp",
            "properties": {
              "PublicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[variables('publicIpAdressRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "frontendPorts": [
          {
            "name": "port_80",
            "properties": {
              "Port": 80
            }
          }
        ],
        "backendAddressPools": [
          {
            "name": "variables('backendAddressPool')",
            "properties": {
              "backendAddresses": [
                {
                  "fqdn": "variables('webSiteUrl')"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "backendHttpSettingsCollection": [
          {
            "name": "variables('backendHttpSettings')",
            "properties": {
              "Port": 80,
              "Protocol": "Http",
              "cookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled",
              "requestTimeout": 20,
              "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": true
            }
          }
        ],
        "httpListeners": [
          {
            "name": "variables('httpListener')",
            "properties": {
              "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                "id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayId'), '/frontendIPConfigurations/appGwPublicFrontendIp')]"
              },
              "frontendPort": {
                "id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayId'), '/frontendPorts/port_80')]"
              },
              "protocol": "Http",
              "sslCertificate": null
            }
          }
        ],
        "requestRoutingRules": [
          {
            "Name": "testRoutingRule",
            "properties": {
              "RuleType": "Basic",
              "httpListener": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/httpListeners', variables('applicationGatewayName'), variables('httpListener'))]"
              },
              "backendAddressPool": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendAddressPools', variables('applicationGatewayName'), variables('backendAddressPool'))]"
              },
              "backendHttpSettings": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendHttpSettingsCollection', variables('applicationGatewayName'), variables('backendHttpSettings'))]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "enableHttp2": true,
        "sslCertificates": [],
        "probes": [],
        "autoscaleConfiguration": {
          "minCapacity": 0,
          "maxCapacity": 10
        },
        "webApplicationFirewallConfiguration": {
          "enabled": true,
          "firewallMode": "Detection",
          "ruleSetType": "OWASP",
          "ruleSetVersion": "3.0"
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you switch convention from  concat(variables... to resourceId(...) when it come to reference httpListener and backendpool etc.

I think resourceid doesn't work as the whole application gateway resource is being created.

I would switch back to using name concatenation to reference a resource.